# Accessing Mesh Renderer Materials Elements in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I haven't prog for a while now and I am starting a 3D game project.
I am trying to make an healthGlobe spawn when I kill an ennemi, so far, everything works out, exept for the material.

I have my material named pink in my assets "Assets/Resources/pink.mat"

I have those lines of code :
[My code][2]

Debug.log said my variable is null
[Null Ref][3]

What is wrong? I can't seem to figure out...

Comment: Your asset needs to be in a "Resources" directory, such as "Assets/Resources". https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html

Comment: 1.Your file must be placed in a folder named Resources. 2.The path you pass to the `Resources.Load` function should be a relative path in the Resources foler. 3.Do not include the file extension. See the duplicate for more info.

Comment: Finally, its better to post your actual code instead of a screenshot of it. This is for your future questions.